# Switched from apache to nginx: PHP Mail no longer working

Tags: nginx, php

I switched to a new server, and from apache to nginx. 
Everything is working great except the php mail function (returning true but mail not received).

What could I have possibly forget to install/configure during the switch that caused the issue ?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 reasons pop to mind

You did not install sendmail.

You did not configure your php.ini for php-fpm correctly.

Comment: Installing sendmail did the trick, thanks. Testing the email I now get a "MyWebsite via subdomain.provider.com". Instead of subdomain.provider.com  I would like my messages to be sent from my original domain, I guess it has to do with headers but I didn't get that problem with my precedent server